# PHP comparing UNIX timestamps

Tags: php, unix, timestamp

I've having an issue comparing two unix timestamps in php.

```
$time_now = mktime();
if($auction->time_end > $time_now){
   //true
}
else{
   //false
}
```

$auction->time_end is 1362579127 and set as int from db.
$time_now is for example 1364129253 and is set as int, both were checking with var_dump and are indeed returning both as ints.

The problem is that PHP seems to think 1362579127 is greater than 1364129253 (returns false) which it is not.. am I missing something here? If I input the values into the if statement it works as it should but when it's comparing the object it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: can you do `var_dump` of `$time_now` and `$auction->time_end` just before the `if` statement, and show exact output here? and are you sure you don't have any spelling error or so, can you show copy/pasted code?

Comment: Var dump of the object int(1362579127) and the mktime int(1364130453)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question it seems you have the logic the wrong way around. The current time is always bigger then a time in the past. Try the following:

```
if($time_now>$auction->time_end){
//...
}
```

Comment: oh god.. late night coding at it's best.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of the int type is defined to be around 2 billion if you're on a 32Bit system. Both of your numbers seem to be too big. See the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: @Sotapanna - a fair point but I don't think this is the issue - the same documentation states that if the interpreter *"encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead."* so it shouldn't affect the comparison?

Comment: @Emissary, true. But dealing with such big numbers seems to cause problems if one is not paying explicit attention to it. I'd recommend using the BCMath library for such operations. http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php