# compare 2 timestamps and execution some code

Tags: php, codeigniter, timestamp

I have two timestamps from a table. Table name is `time_table_list`.

I need to compare these dates and execute code, upon a condition, If `dateA` is less or equal than `dateB` merge code else display a message.

```
$dateA = '1487541600'; 
// timestamp from database
$dateB = '1487541601'; 
// timestamp from database
if($dateA) <= ($dateB){ 
    // code to execut
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP comparing UNIX timestamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598729/php-comparing-unix-timestamps)

Comment: You can learn about the `if` flow control structure here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php CodeIgniter is still PHP thus PHP syntax applies.

Comment: Where is the question mark ->`?`<- Where is the question? Have you ever tested this code snipped? What was the error? But, solution remove one of  `(` and one of `)` and you are fine :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$dateA = 1487541600; 
// timestamp from database
$dateB = 1487541601; 
// timestamp from database
if($dateA <= $dateB){ 
    // code to execute
}
?>
```